# why is this grammar an error 208?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I don't understand why the following grammar leads to error 208 complaining IF will be never matched:

```
error(208): test.g:11:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: IF
```

ANTLRWorks 1.4.3

ANTLT 3.4

```
grammar test;

@lexer::members {
  private boolean rawAhead() {
  }
}

parse    :    IF*;

RAW    :    ({rawAhead()}?=> . )+;
IF      :    'if';
ID    :    ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z')+;
```

Either remove RAW rule or ID rule solves the error...
From my point of view, IF does have the possibility to be matched when rawAhead() returns false.

Comment: Those wanting to answer, posted here as well: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/o2wcpbuiv76mxeph

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that too. But in your case, it doesn't hurt to keep `RAW` at the end, no?

Comment: @bart, yeah, that's me again in the maillist :)

Comment: yeah, I guessed that much. I posted a link in case you get answered there. The funny thing is, when you place `{true}?=>` in front of `'if'`, no error is produced... :|. Might be a bug (ANTLR v3.2 and v3.1 all produce the same error).

Comment: @bart, I think it actually matters, say if we have an and just an 'if' outside of the mmode, e.g. <#/>if<#/>, then the if here will be matched with IF, not RAW it should be (same length, match the first), right?

Comment: hmm, yeah, that _is_ the expected behavior... However, I see something else happening (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

> ***Bood wrote:***
>
> I think it actually matters, say if we have an and just an 'if' outside of the mmode, e.g. <#/>if<#/>, then the if here will be matched with IF, not RAW it should be (same length, match the first), right?

Yeah, you're right, good point. Giving it some more thought that *is* the expected behavior AFAIK. But, it seems things work a bit differently: the `RAW` rule gets precedence over the `ID` and `IF` rules, even when placed at the end of the lexer grammar as you can see:

#### freemarker_simple.g

```java
grammar freemarker_simple;

@lexer::members {

  private boolean mmode = false;

  private boolean rawAhead() {
    if(mmode) return false;
    int ch1 = input.LA(1), ch2 = input.LA(2), ch3 = input.LA(3);
    return !(
        (ch1 == '<' && ch2 == '#') ||
        (ch1 == '<' && ch2 == '/' && ch3 == '#') ||
        (ch1 == '$' && ch2 == '{')
    );
  }
}

parse
  :  (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-15s '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
  ;

OUTPUT_START  : '${'  {mmode=true;};
TAG_START     : '<#'  {mmode=true;};
TAG_END_START : '</' ('#' {mmode=true;} | ~'#' {$type=RAW;});

OUTPUT_END    : '}' {mmode=false;};
TAG_END       : '>' {mmode=false;};

EQUALS        : '==';
IF            : 'if';
STRING        : '"' ~'"'* '"';
ID            : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
SPACE         : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};

RAW           : ({rawAhead()}?=> . )+;
```

#### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    freemarker_simpleLexer lexer = new freemarker_simpleLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("<#/if>if<#if>foo<#if>"));
    freemarker_simpleParser parser = new freemarker_simpleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

will print the following to the console:

```
TAG_START       '<#'
IF              'if'
TAG_END         '>'
RAW             'if'
TAG_START       '<#'
IF              'if'
TAG_END         '>'
RAW             'foo'
TAG_START       '<#'
IF              'if'
TAG_END         '>'
```

As you can see, the `'if'` and `'foo'` *are* tokenized as `RAW` in the input:

```
<#/if>if<#if>foo<#if>
      ^^     ^^^
```

Comment: Tested myself and seems you're right... totally confused about the rule priority now :(

Comment: @Bood, yeah, I am too! Posted a question on the ANTLR list about this: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/mkrpypwuccs25bgd Lets see what the _real_ experts say about this! :)